# Will my data be safe if my laptop is stolen when there is FDE and auto-login?

Tags: security, password, auto-login

My SSD supports Full Disk Encryption (FDE). I have enabled FDE and set a password in BIOS.

In case my laptop is stolen or lost, I want nobody to be able to get my data. Is it now secure to allow auto-login within Ubuntu?

Basically I just don't want to enter 2 passwords when booting, just one.

Comment: Entirely upto you. If you want additional security you shouldn't disable the login password. However, if someone gets to know your encryption password, then the additional security doesn't do much on its own.

Comment: For similar information you can look at this hak5 video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omtbebYaRqw&t=13m26s

Comment: What are you hoping to secure against?

Comment: @ændrük: In case my laptop is stolen or lost, I want nobody to be able to get my data.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to bypass the BIOS password, all one has to do is remove the CMOS battery and put it back in, so I guess it's rather pointless having one. One can enter recovery mode and [reset Ubuntu passwords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) as well, so if the encryption is tied to a user that's a rather useless "protective" measure as well. Read the answers to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68218/ubuntu-if-anyone-can-get-a-root-prompt-without-password-isnt-that-compromisin) question to set up a secure encrypted disk.

Comment: are you sure this also accounts for the hard-drive password? I guess it is saved on the drive itself. A SSD should be able to keep the password, even if there is no power supply..

Comment: @MartinHo I said the BIOS password is stored because of the CMOS battery. The user password is, of course, stored on the drive, but it can be reset following the instructions on the answer I linked, so if the encryption is tied to a user password it is useless. If there is a key which is not stored in the drive and is not tied to the user password, as described in the other question I linked, than it should be as secure as it gets - either way, setting the user password is rather useless.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it now secure to allow auto-login for ubuntu?

No, and it never will. And to me secure means accepting the need to insert passwords.

> Basically I just don't want to enter 2 passwords when booting.

Then remove the one in BIOS and you will have to insert only one password to get to the desktop. BIOS password are security by obscurity: [lots of BIOS passwords have default passwords](http://www.uktsupport.co.uk/reference/biosp.htm). Takes 10 seconds to by-pass any of ones listed in the link.

Comment: The OP has Full Disk Encryption which means he/she has probably used LUKS. The bug report you've mentioned is for the case when the `/home` is encrypted, so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: I was expecting that to be general @green7 removed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Also you can actually login automatically by disabling the login screen, if you use LUKS.